# Connecting to OLAP Cube via Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, mdx, olap

I want to create a **Silverlight** app to extract and manipulate data from an existing **OLAP Cube**. I would like to choose a good approach :

1. Are there some frameworks/librairies?
2. Could it be done without external dependencies?
3. I found some articles talking about **Web Services** with **MS Analysis Services**. Should I avoid connecting directly to the **OLAP Cube** and make some **Web Services**?

**Progress :**

The cube is deployed on **SSAS**, I could access it and execute **MDX query** from **MS SQL Server Management Studio**. Is there an example how to launch an **MDX Query** from a **Silverlight** page and display the result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only speak to SSAS.

1. If you are connecting to SQL Server Analysis Server, you can use ADO MD.Net objects. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123483.aspx). Or you can use the HTTP Pump. (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917711.aspx)
2. The HTTP pump might eliminate some dependancies for you.
3. It depends on what your goal is. Service 
   based architecture (be it web, or some other tech) is up to the designer and requirements of your application. You can do this pretty easily however. I've polled a SSAS cube using a WCF service before and it worked well to limit requests to the cube.

Tutorials are scarce on the internet. Your best bet is to buy a book specific to the type of OLAP server you are using.

Here is a comprehensive list about how to connect to SSAS using various clients:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174518

Comment: Thanks, i'm looking, this should be helpfull to know how to connect to OLAP Cube. But i don't see anything about Silverlight, can all the proposed solutions be consumed by a Silverlight client ?

Comment: It depends how you want to consume it I guess. If you want an excel like power-pivot, you're probably going to need something like Telerik. If you just want to do MDX queries to a 2 dimensional table to display, you can pretty much use and table/grid/graph control you'd like. It really depends on what you need to display. MDX can give you the x/y tables pretty easily. It can also bring back multi-dimensional data that will need a more robust control to display

Comment: I lied: http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/pivotviewer/ looks like a SL control that can hit SSAS doing a pivot.

Comment: Suppose i have the cube already deployed on a SSAS Server, how should i proceed to Connect and Browse it from a silverlight client ? Do you know a good tutorial ?

Comment: http://www.rogernoble.com/2011/05/27/using-ssis-to-generate-pivotviewer-cxml-from-ssas/  This guy is doing exactly what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

i think one of the best solution fo you 
is to try this  OLAP Silverlight soulution

```
http://www.galantis.com/ranet/
```

Comment: Thanks but I already bought a Telerik, and i'm not planning to buy another one ...

Comment: I will use it in my company so i should buy it : http://www.galantis.com/ranet/price